# SSRS Schedules disappeared and emailing has ceased

Tags: reporting-services

For some reason our SSRS schedules appear to have stopped running over the weekend.
I checked the schedules on our SSRS portal, these appear to have disappeared "There are no items to show in this view". I get the same under my subscriptions, too.
The agent jobs appear to be running, but not emailing reports. When I check the Subscriptions on SSMS, it has run dates for today but no emails.
I have sysadmin and full rights to the server and the SSRS portal.
Anyone come across this issue? I've been searching google all morning to no avail.

Thanks,
Russ

Comment: Who owns the subscriptions?  Perhaps their account is no longer active?

Comment: I've had times where email stopped, though the issue wasn't SSRS per se, rather, it was SQL Server not sending out mail.Do you have lots of queued mail that haven't been sent out?

Comment: Jobs are run under a proxy account which is currently active.
My counterpart DBA who set these up has gone on A/L, but he's account is still active.

Comment: Hi Eli,
When I check Database Mail under management, I can't see any queues. Is this where you would normally check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved
Our SSRS dba had only place schedules onto reports locally - you can see this by clicking on the drop down arrow of the report, selecting manage, and then subscriptions from there.
The reason our reports weren't sending is because there was mail delivery had been suspended whilst IT carried out maintenance.

Thanks for your help in trying to get to the bottom of this.